# ten minutes free vs free ten minutes?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Are there two both correct?

> Do you have **ten minutes** `free` to discuss research paper?

> Do you have `free` **ten minutes** to discuss research paper?

Does "have **ten minutes** `free`" means "have **ten minutes** *which is* `free`"?

or it just means  "have **something** `in a particular state`"?

with the form of Verb + **Noun** + `Adjective`

Comment: Personally, I find both orders acceptable (except that you can't spell **minutes**!), but I would say "**a** free ten minutes" (meaning "a free period of about 10 min.").

Comment: I don't find the second version remotely acceptable without the indefinite article. Personally I don't like the second format with ***specific numbers of minutes*** anyway (and ***a few free minutes*** and ***a free few minutes*** both sound awful to me), but it's perfectly natural with, say, *Do you have **a free half-hour** to discuss this?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

- **a free** ten minutes
- ten **free** minutes
- ten minutes **free**

Answer (score 2):

"Free ten minutes" lacks a determiner at the start of the noun phrase; you would need to say "ten free minutes."

Regardless, "ten minutes free" is the idiomatic expression.